# Regex to match four blocks ranges

Tags: php, regex

Can someone help me build a regex that can check four blocks containing text and numbers separated by hyphens?

I'm trying the following:

```
/([a-z0-9]{4,10})-([a-z0-9]{4,10})-([a-z0-9]{4,10})-([a-z0-9]{4,10})/
```

It works for: `12345-1234-1b3456-12c4567e910` and for `abc1-ab2de-ab4def-abcdef0`

But it's also working for: `12345-1234-1b3456-1234567891011`

I need the regex to be invalid when this outside any of the 4 blocks (minimum 4 and maximum 10).

Comment: Wrap the pattern in `/^...$/` to [make it match](https://regex101.com/r/kZN7MQ/1) if only the whole string matches it. As of now, the pattern matches [just a portion of string](https://regex101.com/r/wIk3SC/1) in the 2nd case.

Comment: Thank U, I'm a regex newbie =).

Comment: Closed as duplicate; while the original question was about JS regex, and this one is about PHP regex, the boundary anchors are actually supported universally. And yes, you're welcome. )